# Creating a 3D surface plot from GridsearchCV

Tags: python, optimization, scikit-learn, mplot3d, grid-search

I am using GridsearchCV in an attempt to optimize values of c and gamma. I would like to be able to plot a 3d surface showing how the accuracy (mean validation score) varies with different values of c and gamma. I think the gridscores output is a list of tuples with the parameters (gamma and c) as a dict. I'm not sure on how I can efficiently turn this into the 2d arrays required for the mplot3d surface plot.

So when I run:

```
grid.grid_scores_
```

I get an output like:

```
[mean: 0.91667, std: 0.03493, params: {'C': 10.0, 'gamma': 1e-05},
mean: 0.84167, std: 0.05388, params: {'C': 10.0, 'gamma': 0.0001},
mean: 0.80000, std: 0.02703, params: {'C': 10.0, 'gamma': 0.001},...]
```

And so on.